# Array of ints in numba

Tags: python, performance, numpy, types, numba

I am calculating the most frequent number in a vector of `int8`s. Numba complains when I set up a counter array of `int`s:

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def freq_int8(y):
    """Find most frequent number in array"""
    count = np.zeros(256, dtype=int)
    for val in y:
        count[val] += 1
    return ((np.argmax(count)+128) % 256) - 128
```

Calling it I get the following error:

```
TypingError: Invalid usage of Function(<built-in function zeros>) with parameters (int64, Function(<class 'int'>))
```

If I delete `dtype=int` it works and I get a decent speedup. I am however puzzled as to why declaring an array of `int`s isn't working. Is there a known workaround, and would there be any efficiency gain worth having here?

**Background**: I am trying to shave microseconds off some numpy-heavy code. I am especially being hurt by `numpy.median`, and have been looking into Numba, but am struggling to improve on `median`. Finding the most frequent number is an acceptable alternative to `median`, and here I've been able to gain some performance. The above numba code is also faster than `numpy.bincount`.

**Update:** After input in the accepted answer, here's an implementation of `median` for `int8` vectors. It is roughly an order of magnitude faster than `numpy.median`:

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def median_int8(y):
    N2 = len(y)//2
    count = np.zeros(256, dtype=np.int32)
    for val in y:
        count[val] += 1
    cs = 0
    for i in range(-128, 128):
        cs += count[i]
        if cs > N2:
            return float(i)
        elif cs == N2:
            j = i+1
            while count[j] == 0:
                j += 1
            return (i + j)/2
```

Surprisingly, the performance difference is even greater for short vectors, apparently due to overhead in `numpy` vectors:

```
>>> a = np.random.randint(-128, 128, 10)

>>> %timeit np.median(a)
    The slowest run took 7.03 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
    10000 loops, best of 3: 20.8 µs per loop

>>> %timeit median_int8(a)
    The slowest run took 11.67 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
    1000000 loops, best of 3: 593 ns per loop
```

This overhead is so large, I'm wondering if something is wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just a quick note, finding the most frequent number is normally called [*mode*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics)), and it is as similar to the *median* as it is the *mean*... in which case `np.mean` will be considerably faster. Unless you have some constrains or particularities in your data, [there is no guarantee that the *mode* approximates the *median*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics)#Comparison_of_mean.2C_median_and_mode).

If you still want to calculate the *mode* of a list of integer numbers, [`np.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html), as you mention, should be enough (if numba is faster, it shouldn't be by much):

```
count = np.bincount(y, minlength=256)
result = ((np.argmax(count)+128) % 256) - 128
```

Note I've added the `minlength` parameter to `np.bincount` just so it returns the same 256 length list that you have in your code. But it is completely unnecessary in practice, as you only want the `argmax`, `np.bincount` (without `minlength`) will return a list which length is the maximum number in `y`.

As for the numba error, replacing `dtype=int` with `dtype=np.int32` should solve the problem. `int` is a python function, and you are specifying `nopython` in the numba header. If you remove `nopython`, then either `dtype=int` or `dtype='i'` will also work (having the same effect).

Comment: So that's what _mode_ means! Yes, I understand the difference to median, but in my particular use-case, mode is probably even more appropriate than median. Your suggestion of using dtype=np.int32, does indeed work, and provided a further 30% speedup.  As for `bincount`, that also works as wanted, but is roughly half as fast as the numba version.

Comment: @DNF numba is indeed faster than bincount, but note that the first call of numba is always slower (unless you call it with very big arrays). If you are defining the function to call it only once (in an small array), then the speed with be considerably worse than `np.bincount`. If on the other hand, if you are calling the function multiple times, or with an array big enough so that numba can optimize it *on the fly*, numba should work fine.

Comment: It should be running for millions or tens or millions of times per session, and will be running across several processors. But do you happen to know if starting a new process will trigger a new compilation?

Comment: @DNF Depends of by *processor* you mean an actual python process or a *thread*. But my first guess would be to say *yes*, it will trigger a new compilation. However, if the arrays are large, numba will compile it *on the fly* making it fast, so you don't have to worry about. And, if the arrays are small, the time lost in the first run will be insignificant. So either way, if you run it millions of times, it should be fine.

Comment: For completeness, here's my implementation of median for int8 vectors: `@jit(nopython=True)
def median_int8(y):
    N2 = len(y)//2
    count = np.zeros(256, dtype=np.int32)
    for val in y:
        count[val] += 1
    cs = 0
    for i in range(-128, 128):
        cs += count[i]
        if cs < N2:
            continue
        elif cs > N2:
            return float(i)
        else:
            j = i+1
            while count[j] == 0:
                j += 1
            return (i + j)/2`
It is roughly an order of magnitude faster than `numpy.median`.

Ouch, ugly formatting!

Comment: @DNF Hahaha formatting code in comments is kinda crappy. You can probably edit the question and add it bellow for future views to the question!